# SuiteCRM listview conditional formatting

Tags: javascript, listview, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm trying to figure out how to make listview/subpanel rows in my SuiteCRM database a certain color based on a dropdown selection. For example, if "Verified" is selected from the dropdown, the row should be yellow.

I know you can do this somehow using a combination of logic hooks and javascript, but it's beyond my meager coding powers. Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can change color in list view by customizing view.list.php in custom/modules/modulename/views/view.list.php using following code:

```
<?php
require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.list.php');
require_once('custom/modules/Leads/LeadsListViewSmarty.php');
class LeadsViewList extends ViewList {
    /**
     * @see ViewList::preDisplay()
     */
    public function preDisplay() {
        $jsscript = <<<EOQ
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("form#MassUpdate table.list.view td:contains('Not Changed')").css('background-color', 'Green');
$("form#MassUpdate table.list.view td:contains('Station Changed')").css('background-color', 'red');
   });
</script>
EOQ;
        parent::preDisplay();
        echo $jsscript;     //echo the script
        $this->lv = new LeadsListViewSmarty();
    }
}
?>
```